# How to use different kind of Google Font types?

Tags: css, fonts

I want to use a Google Font with different types (Light, Black, Semi-bold).

This is the link for the Google Font: https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:300,400,600,900

The regular is working fine, `font-family: 'Exo 2';` But I was wondering how I can use the Light, Black ones. I've tried Exo 2 Black/Light but that didn't seem to work.

I've also read the documentation, but that didn't have the answer also.

Comment: there is no light and black font. all what you can do is to set font-weight

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You first have to load you font in the document's head and than use the font in conjunction with the right `font-weight` in your CSS.

PS: You got a little typo in your font URL.

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Website</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:300,400,600,900" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="path/to/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  …
</body>
</html>
```

`styles.css`

```
.light {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 300;
}

.normal {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.semi-bold {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 600;
}

.black {
  font-family: 'Exo 2';
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `font-weight` property in your css with the correct numeric representation of the font-weights.

In your case, you can see in the URL the different weights available:
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:300,400,600,900

The 300,400,600,900 correspond to font weights.

- 300 - Light
- 400 - Regular (so no need to declare it)
- 600 - Bold
- 900 - Black

in your case `font-weight: 300` would be light and `font-weight: 900` would be black.